# Trying to optimize simple PLL phase discriminator - Isn't there an off-the-shelf equivalent?

Tags: flipflop, pll, phase

What I'm after is the "number 3" phase discriminator from the venerable 4046 PLL. That is, an edge-detected SR latch, effectively. A rising edge on input 1 makes the output go high. A rising edge on input 2 makes the output return low.

That's it. No fancy shenanigans. Here's one:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRyjRH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Trouble is, that's a bunch of discrete logic. The 4046 is one TSSOP-16 package, but you throw away most of the functionality.

Frankly, I just can't believe that this exact thing isn't available as a SOT23-5 out there somewhere. But all of the SR latch / flip-flops I find on DigiKey are neither edge triggered, nor are they positive (rising edge) logic.

Comment: Well, the original schematic I put in the question probably won't work, as it will oscillate if both inputs are held high.

Comment: If it fit's your function use it.  I've used the 4046 for just it's VCO.

Comment: I've used it just for the comparator- cheaper than the alternatives. Why not? Silicon is cheap and plentiful.

Answer (score 1):

According to the 1984 National Semiconductor CMOS databook, Phase Comparator I is a simple XOR gate, which maintains a 90° relationship between its inputs. Phase Comparator III is a simple S-R latch (level-sensitive, not edge-sensitive), which maintains a 180° phase relationship between the two inputs. It requires that the signals be conditioned externally to narrow pulses, so the schematic in your question is pretty much it.

Phase Comparator II is the true edge-sensitive logic that drives the inputs to be in-phase (0°). The full implementation (from the databook) is reproduced below. I guess most people today would implement this as part of their CPLD or FPGA.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUFfiG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: The ON Semi data sheet I'm looking at says that the inputs to the phase comparator 3 latch come from the PC2 pulse detection outputs. For my particular application, PC2 would require a bit more complication in the loop filter. It's a long story not interesting for this particular question.